# Undecidability in the context of modern programming languages

Tags: undecidability

Imagine a program, executed by an interpreter to be a Turing Machine. Consider this code:

```
x = read_input
print x
```

Does undecidability mean that there may possibly be an input to this program such that the program may never halt?

Comment: Well, in that case, presumably the program won't terminate if the input stream never ends. This isn't really within the realms of Turing machine computation, where the input is normally assumed to be finite.

Comment: I'm guessing what you really wanted is something like `x = raw_input() \n eval(x) \n print "input program terminates"`? This takes an input program and outputs "input program terminates" if and only if the input read from `raw_input()` is a valid Python program that terminates.

Comment: @JuzerAli, it would help if you described what `read_input` does more carefully (does it read a fixed amount of input, or read until end of file?).

Comment: @D.W.I guess it reads till end of file.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as a programming/software development question. Although it mentions Python, my impression is that it's not about Python *per se*, and certainly not about programming, but about the relationship between the halting problem and actual programming languages, with Python used as an example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah thats what I meant when I said python. I was just using it as an example. The problem is with hackers who haven't had a chance to learn CS theory, we can only understand in terms of actual programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

Undecidability is a property of problems, not of programs. What is undecidable is however to check if some given program ever halts on any input. *This problem has the program as input.*

If you fix a program, then it *may* be decidable to check if the program halts for some input. *This problem has the program input as input.* In particular, for programs such as yours that *always* terminate, the termination problem is decidable, meaning there exists an algorithm for it: it just outputs "yes".

Note that the term "undecidability" only has a meaning in environments that allow arbitrary memory size and arbitrary input size. The Python language may fit to this definition, but the interpreter your are using certainly doesn't.

Comment: So let me put it this way. Python interpreter can be seen as a TM. It accepts python language. My question is what does undecidability mean in context of python. Is following statement true about undecidability: There exists a string which is not valid python language string but the interpreter may never halt to tell us that it isn't.

Comment: A program is valid python if it is syntactically valid. Syntactic validity of Python programs is decidable and the interpreter certainly uses an algorithm for it that is guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: I understand what you mean by arbitrary memory and input size.

Comment: This answer is very vague: so much so that I can't even tell if it's correct. What does "check if some arbitrary program ever halts on any input" mean? Does it mean "Given a program $P$, determine whether there is any input that makes $P$ halt"? "Given $P$, determine whether $P$ halts on all inputs"? "Given $P$ and $x$, determine whether $P$ halts for input $x$"? One of those things but $P$ is a fixed program? Something else? Please try to write more precisely and make your quantifiers explicit.

Comment: So I guess this statement should be correct. It is impossible to create a program which can accept a valid python program `P` and its input `x` as input and decide whether `P` halts on `x`.

Comment: @JuzerAli This last comment of yours is a correct and true statement.

Answer (score 4):

Undecidability tells us that, given an arbitrary program and some input, there is no general computational procedure which tells us whether that program halts on that input.

It says nothing about specific computational procedures which may be correct for specific (classes of) programs. That is, we can generate heuristics which correctly answer the question for some programs; the more complicated we're willing to make the heuristics, the more programs may be potentially covered. All that undecidability says is that no finite set of heuristics is going to correctly cover all cases.

To illustrate, we can start developing heuristics to decide whether a program $P$ halts on an input $x$. Let's narrow down our language first: we'll assume a procedural language, with no function calls, and the only control flow constructs are `while` and `if-else`. On the right machine, this system is Turing-equivalent.

> If the program doesn't contain a `while` loop, then it halts.
>
> If every basic block in the program contains a `return` statement, then it halts.

You can take this as far as you want to go, defining a sort of "halting semantics" for your programming language. The semantics will never be correct for all possible programs - if your language/machine is Turing-equivalent - but you can do pretty good. The above (correct) heuristics are enough to definitively answer the example in your question.